# Substitution rule for vim's Quickfix window

Tags: vim

I have a C++ project with `*.cpp` files located in `c:\project`. I'm also using a pseudo-out-of-tree build system, which uses `c:\project\build` directory as an output directory for every executable, object file, autogenerated file, etc.

Normally I'm launching `vim` when my `PWD` is `c:\project`:

```
$ vim <file>
```

When I use `:make` command, my build tool launches and begins to compile the project. In case of any errors, I'm getting the usual error list in the Quickfix window (`:cope`). The problem is that "my" build tool (btw, it's `waf` tool) is executed from the `c:\project\build` directory, not `c:\project`, so any references to source files will be printed out relatively to `c:\project\build` directory. This means that for this file: `c:\project\main.cpp`, in case of an error I'll get error message like:

```
..\main.cpp:9:0: <errormessage>
```

Vim's `g++` parser takes this error line, extracts the file from it (`..\main.cpp`), but it won't open it after I click enter, because vim's session's PWD is `c:\project`. After clicking enter, vim tries to open `c:\main.cpp`.

I can just start vim from the `c:\project\build` directory and it's working, but this in turn causes problems with vim plugins like `CtrlP`, so I'd like to start vim session from project's root, not build's root.

Is it possible for vim to substitute the `..\` to an empty string? I'm asking for a [similar option that gdb has](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) (source path substitution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to find the solution shortly after posting the question. I need to practice rubber-duck debugging more.

I've fixed this by creating a build script (`m.cmd`):

```
@echo off
waf 2>&1 | sed "s#^..\\##g"
```

and I did set `:set makeprg=m.cmd`.

Now it works as expected.